# Concatenate multiple strings ordered (PIVOT)

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse, string-aggregation, conditional-aggregation

I'm trying to concatenate the names of multiple Employees (ordered) based on their hierarchical level, which ranges between 0 and 4, without duplicates. The issue itself is fairly easy to solve (although I used Group By when a PIVOT would most likely be ideal), however, when I try to use `STRING_AGG` with ordering statements, Synapse Analytics says I cannot order by all of these, I get the error:

> Multiple ordered aggregate functions in the same scope have mutually incompatible orderings.

For instance, consider the following data:

```
Department  | Employee Name  | Level
----------------------------------------
     A        |     John          |   0
     A        |    Andrew         |   0
     A        |   McKenzee        |   1
     A        |    Alissa         |   2
     B        |   Catherine       |   0
     B        |      Jack         |   1
     B        |      Jack         |   1
     B        |      Luanne       |   1
     B        |      Abigail      |   2
```

The expected output would be:

```
Department    |     Level 0           | Level 1           | Level 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------
     A        |     Andrew, John      |   McKenzee        | Alissa
     B        |     Catherine         |   Jack, Luanne    | Abigail
```

However, doing so results in the error above:

```
select
    ...
from
(
select
    department
    ,STRING_AGG(level_0, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY level_0) level_0
    ,STRING_AGG(level_1, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY level_1) level_1
    ,STRING_AGG(level_2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY level_2) level_2
    ,STRING_AGG(level_3, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY level_3) level_3
  from
  (
    select
      department
      ,case 
        when employee_level = 0 then employee_name
      end level_0
      ,case 
        when employee_level = 1 then employee_name
      end level_1
      ,case 
        when employee_level = 2 then employee_name
      end level_2
      ,case 
        when employee_level = 3 then employee_name
      end level_3
      ,case 
        when employee_level = 4 then employee_name
      end level_4
    from
      employee_records
    group by
         department
  ) base_
  group by
    department
) le_subquery
```

Note: Since this is actually a subquery within a higher query I cannot use the `Order By` statement.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use conditional aggregation in a `STRING_AGG`

```sql
SELECT
  Department,
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Level = 0 THEN Employee END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Employee) level_0,
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Level = 1 THEN Employee END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Employee) level_1,
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Level = 2 THEN Employee END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Employee) level_2,
  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Level = 3 THEN Employee END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Employee) level_3
FROM @tbl
GROUP BY Department;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/CMxZN7Pt)

Comment: Eventually, I came up with the same solution just using `IIF` instead of `CASE` statement.

Comment: Yeah basically the same (it even compiles the same) just `CASE` is more standardized and well-known.